# Array of ImageView not working

Tags: java, android

I have ImageView array but when i am setting image within java its not working ,it is using the default image that has been define in xml layout

```
private ImageView[]  imageView=new ImageView[2];

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_selection_activity);

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        imageView[i]=new ImageView(this);

    imageView[0]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selection_one);
    imageView[1]= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selection_two);
    imageView[0].setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_network_wifi_black_48dp);
    imageView[1].setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_network_wifi_black_48dp);
}
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#96000000"
>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_one" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_two"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/selection_three"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_four"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_five"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_six"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_seven"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_eight"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bubble_dimension"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/selection_nine"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_info_black_48dp"/>

    </TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

Please help and when i am using ImageView without array its working fine

PS : onClicklistener are working perfectly on these imageView[i]

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you show the XML?

Comment: Still works fine, with your XML. Try to clean the project.

Comment: There was mistake ,I found it thanks anyway

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: I was initializing images within a for loop as there are 9 imageview but i pasted code that was inside for loop , mistake was in for loop condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Resources resources = getResources();
imageView[0].setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_network_wifi_black_48dp));
imageView[1].setImageDrawable(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_network_wifi_black_48dp));
```